# Aligning Legend at the top right on ZedGraph

Tags: zedgraph

Aligning Legend at the top right on ZedGraph.

```
 myPane.Legend.Position = ZedGraph.LegendPos.TopCenter; // This way working.
```

I tried this way and has not worked.

```
 //myPane.Legend.Location.AlignH = AlignH.Right;
//myPane.Legend.Location.AlignV = AlignV.Top;
//Location(0.95, 0.15,);// CoordType.PaneFraction, AlignH.Right, AlignV.Top);
//AlignV.Top; //(0.95, 0.15, CoordType.PaneFraction, AlignH.Right, AlignV.Top);
```

Any suggestions.
Thanks
ocaccy

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to align the legend to the top right, one way is:

```
myPane.Legend.Position = ZedGraph.LegendPos.Right;
```

or if you want the legend inside the graph area:

```
myPane.Legend.Position = ZedGraph.LegendPos.InsideTopRight;
```